# Angular upgrade issue : TS2339: property does not exist on type for imported object within json

Tags: json, angular, import, upgrade

I am upgradeing Angular 7 to 16, the import object from json file worked fine in Angular 7 now breaks. It complains "TS2339:  property does not exist on type for imported object within json "

Answer (score 0):

Originally in Angular 7, my json file contains "object1" and "object2", I directly

```
import {object1} from data.json;
import {object2} from data.json ;
```

Now in Angular 16, I have to do it this way.

```
import jsondata from data.json;
```

there is no {} around jsondata;
then access object1/2 using jsondata[object1/2],